# Workaround for dictsort-ing by model method as of Django 4.0.1

Tags: django, django-templates

It helps to read the release notes. After three hours of debugging, I finally found out that my code stopped working in Django 4.0.1 due to the removed functionality to use model method for `dictsort`-ing. It is documented in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0.1/):

> CVE-2021-45116:
> In order to avoid [potential information disclosure], dictsort now
> works with a restricted resolution logic, that will not call methods,
> nor allow indexing on dictionaries.

Now I wonder what to do. I need to sort my list by a value that is not stored in the database but is calculated based on a value in the database. Is it a bad practice? What is a better one? Unfortunately, the generally very helpful documentation is silent about it so far.

By the way—I am not sure this is the right place to ask, but out of curiosity—is it the intended behaviour that `dictsort` doesn't throw an error but just silently returns an empty list in case of calling it on a model method?

Comment: Curious, what's stopping your from doing the sorting in a view and then passing the value in the template?

Comment: Nothing :) It just didn't come to my mind! Still, it would be interesting to know if a template-based workaround exists, for the sake of learning.

Comment: Then the other option would be to write your own template tag and use that in the template instead

Comment: @MohitSolanki care to write an answer so I can accept it? Both solutions are good.